# Jenkins CLI -- how to build a job in a subdirectory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-cli

I am trying to build a job using jenkins-cli.jar, but I cannot figure out how to tell Jenkins the job is in a subdirectory.

```
$ java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://myserver/ list-jobs util --username Jerry --password swordfish
TheJobIWant
AnotherJob
SomeOtherJob
```

So the job is clearly there, inside that folder. But when I try to run it, I get:

```
$ java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s https://myserver/ build util/TheJobIWant -s --username Jerry --password swordfish
No such job 'util/TheJobIWant'
```

How am I supposed to call this job from the CLI?

Comment: Were you able to call/build jobs before that weren't in the sub directory? Is this your first time to build the job thru CLI? Make sure you passed the SSH authentication, and that you have enough permission in the job folder.

Comment: Well, it seems to be a permissions issue. I created a new job, buildable by anonymous, and temporarily allowed the anonymous user read and execute privileges on the entire Jenkins instance. That new job worked in the CLI. So I guess I just have to nail down my security model properly.

Comment: I solved this, at least temporarily, by adding the privilege "Job > Read" on the job's parent directory for the anonymous user. This seems like the wrong way to solve it, but I don't see any security holes created by doing this, so I think I'll stick with it.  

@jinggoy, I set up the SSH authentication by entering my public key in https://myserver/me/configure, but this doesn't seem to have made any difference. Is there some other way of doing this? It seems strange to me anyhow that I would need an SSH key to access things through https ...

Answer (score 0):

When you were saying 'subdirectory', do you mean 'subview' ?

I've created a job named 'job1' under the **netsted view-->subview** folder.
[image]
When I tried to trigger a build from jenkins command line, I was using:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ build job1 --username admin --password admin
```

And as you can see, 'job1' has successfully been triggered.

[image]

Hope this helps!

Comment: No -- I am using the Jenkins Folders plugin to group my jobs. I wonder if I can use a view as a kludge for this ...

Comment: @Jerry Ok，I have been using nested view to group my jobs for a long time. we have 1000+ jobs in my company and view just woks well

Comment: What's your security model for this instance of Jenkins? I have a few jobs that I can't allow general access to, and they're easy enough to manage now that there are only a few, but if there comes to be a lot more I am looking forward to using folders to easily secure large numbers of jobs. Can you do the same with a view?

Comment: @Jerry, first, we are using openid as a login strategy. Second, we use Project-based Matrix Authorization Strategy to control the access. Only who is the view owner have the authority to edit jobs and views. But you are correct, currently we do not have a good solution to limit the access rights of view owners. That means view A's owner can also access/edit/delete view B.

Answer (score 0):

May want to check out https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-11024.  There is a workaround by allowing anonymous users read-access to the jobs, but that's not always suitable for every installation.

Answer (score 0):

Use -i  option instead of --username --password. Or curl as mentioned in https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-12543